# Pyspark: weighted average by a column

Tags: matrix, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

For example, I have a dataset like this

```
test = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, 1, 5, "2018-06-03", "Region A"),
    (1, 1, 2, "2018-06-04", "Region B"),
    (2, 2, 1, "2018-06-03", "Region B"),
    (3, 3, 1, "2018-06-01", "Region A"),
    (3, 1, 3, "2018-06-05", "Region A"),
])\
  .toDF("orderid", "customerid", "price", "transactiondate", "location")
test.show()
```

and I can obtain the customer-region order count matrix by

```
overall_stat = test.groupBy("customerid").agg(count("orderid"))\
  .withColumnRenamed("count(orderid)", "overall_count")
temp_result = test.groupBy("customerid").pivot("location").agg(count("orderid")).na.fill(0).join(overall_stat, ["customerid"])

for field in temp_result.schema.fields:
    if str(field.name) not in ['customerid', "overall_count", "overall_amount"]:
        name = str(field.name)
        temp_result = temp_result.withColumn(name, col(name)/col("overall_count"))
temp_result.show()
```

The data would look like this

[image]

Now, I want to calculate the weighted average by the `overall_count`, how can I do it?

The result should be `(0.66*3+1*1)/4` for region A, and `(0.33*3+1*1)/4` for region B

---

My thoughts:

It can certainly be achieved through turning the data into python/pandas and then do some calculation, but in what cases should we use Pyspark?

I can get something like

```
temp_result.agg(sum(col("Region A") * col("overall_count")), sum(col("Region B")*col("overall_count"))).show()
```

but it doesn't feel right, especially if there is many `region`s to count.

Comment: You can refer to my previously asked question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47622447/weighted-moving-average-in-pyspark

Answer (score 2):

you can achieve a weighted average by breaking your above steps into multiple stages.

Consider the following:

```
Dataframe Name: sales_table
[ total_sales, count_of_orders, location]
[     50     ,       9        ,    A    ]
[     80     ,       4        ,    A    ]
[     90     ,       7        ,    A    ]
```

To calculate the grouped weighted average of the above (70) is broken into two steps:

1. Multiplying `sales` by `importance`
2. Aggregating the `sales_x_count` product
3. Dividing `sales_x_count` by the sum of the original

If we break the above into several stages within our PySpark code, you can get the following:

```
new_sales = sales_table \
    .withColumn("sales_x_count", col("total_sales") * col("count_orders")) \
    .groupBy("Location") \
    .agg(sf.sum("total_sales").alias("sum_total_sales"), \
         sf.sum("sales_x_count").alias("sum_sales_x_count")) \
    .withColumn("count_weighted_average", col("sum_sales_x_count") / col("sum_total_sales"))
```

So... no fancy UDF is really necessary here (and would likely slow you down).