# Column with avg over previous day pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to create a new column which is the mean of previous day sales using pyspark.

consider these value are at different timestamp.

for eg  convert this:

```
| Date       | value |
|------------|-------|
| 2019/02/11 | 30    |
| 2019/02/11 | 40    |
| 2019/02/11 | 20    |
| 2019/02/12 | 10    |
| 2019/02/12 | 15    |
```

to this

```
| Date       | value | avg  |
|------------|-------|------|
| 2019/02/11 | 30    | null |
| 2019/02/11 | 40    | null |
| 2019/02/11 | 20    | null |
| 2019/02/12 | 10    | 30   |
| 2019/02/12 | 15    | 30   |
```

My thinking :

Use filter and aggregation function to obtain average but its throwing error. Not sure where I am doing wrong.

```
df = df.withColumn("avg",lit((df.filter(df["date"] == date_sub("date",1)).agg({"value": "avg"}))))
```

Comment: You can look at this answer as well : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47622447/weighted-moving-average-in-pyspark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using the windows functions but you have to create a new column to handle the dates. 
I added few lines to you example :

```py
df.withColumn(
  "rnk",
  F.dense_rank().over(Window.partitionBy().orderBy("date"))
).withColumn(
  "avg",
  F.avg("value").over(Window.partitionBy().orderBy("rnk").rangeBetween(-1,-1))
).show()

+----------+-----+---+----+
|      date|value|rnk| avg|
+----------+-----+---+----+
|2018-01-01|   20|  1|null|
|2018-01-01|   30|  1|null|
|2018-01-01|   40|  1|null|
|2018-01-02|   40|  2|30.0|
|2018-01-02|   30|  2|30.0|
|2018-01-03|   40|  3|35.0|
|2018-01-03|   40|  3|35.0|
+----------+-----+---+----+
```

You can also do that using aggregation :

```
agg_df = df.withColumn("date", F.date_add("date", 1)).groupBy('date').avg("value")
df.join(agg_df, how="full_outer", on="date").orderBy("date").show()

+----------+-----+----------+
|      date|value|avg(value)|
+----------+-----+----------+
|2018-01-01|   20|      null|
|2018-01-01|   30|      null|
|2018-01-01|   40|      null|
|2018-01-02|   30|      30.0|
|2018-01-02|   40|      30.0|
|2018-01-03|   40|      35.0|
|2018-01-03|   40|      35.0|
|2018-01-04| null|      40.0|
+----------+-----+----------+
```

Comment: rangeBetween(-1,-1) why this is used can you explain ?

Comment: Sure. It takes the value in "rnk" in your current row and adds -1 (removes 1 basically). So, when you are looking at rows with rnk = 2, it takes only rows with value 1.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 0:** Creating a DataFrame

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, avg, lag
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('2019/02/11',30),('2019/02/11',40),('2019/02/11',20),
                                 ('2019/02/12',10),('2019/02/12',15),
                                 ('2019/02/13',10),('2019/02/13',20)],['Date','value'])
```

**Step 1:** First calculating the average and then using [windows](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html) function to get the lag by 1 day.

```
my_window = Window.partitionBy().orderBy('Date')
df_avg_previous = df.groupBy('Date').agg(avg(col('value')).alias('avg'))
df_avg_previous = df_avg_previous.withColumn('avg', lag(col('avg'),1).over(my_window))
df_avg_previous.show()
+----------+----+
|      Date| avg|
+----------+----+
|2019/02/11|null|
|2019/02/12|30.0|
|2019/02/13|12.5|
+----------+----+
```

**Step 2:** Finally joining the two dataframes by using a `left` join.

```
df = df.join(df_avg_previous, ['Date'],how='left').orderBy('Date')
df.show()
+----------+-----+----+
|      Date|value| avg|
+----------+-----+----+
|2019/02/11|   40|null|
|2019/02/11|   20|null|
|2019/02/11|   30|null|
|2019/02/12|   10|30.0|
|2019/02/12|   15|30.0|
|2019/02/13|   10|12.5|
|2019/02/13|   20|12.5|
+----------+-----+----+
```