# Pyspark: How to code Complicated Dataframe algorithm problem (summing with condition)

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a dataframe looks like this:

```
TEST_schema = StructType([StructField("date", StringType(), True),\
                              StructField("Trigger", StringType(), True),\
                              StructField("value", FloatType(), True),\
                              StructField("col1", IntegerType(), True),
                             StructField("col2", IntegerType(), True),
                             StructField("want", FloatType(), True)])
TEST_data = [('2020-08-01','T',0.0,3,5,0.5),('2020-08-02','T',0.0,-1,4,0.0),('2020-08-03','T',0.0,-1,3,0.0),('2020-08-04','F',0.2,3,3,0.7),('2020-08-05','T',0.3,1,4,0.9),\
                 ('2020-08-06','F',0.2,-1,3,0.0),('2020-08-07','T',0.2,-1,4,0.0),('2020-08-08','T',0.5,-1,5,0.0),('2020-08-09','T',0.0,-1,5,0.0)]
rdd3 = sc.parallelize(TEST_data)
TEST_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(TEST_data, TEST_schema)
TEST_df = TEST_df.withColumn("date",to_date("date", 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
TEST_df.show()
```

```
+----------+-------+-----+----+----+
|      date|Trigger|value|col1|col2|
+----------+-------+-----+----+----+
|2020-08-01|      T|  0.0|   3|   5| 
|2020-08-02|      T|  0.0|  -1|   4| 
|2020-08-03|      T|  0.0|  -1|   3| 
|2020-08-04|      F|  0.2|   3|   3| 
|2020-08-05|      T|  0.3|   1|   4|
|2020-08-06|      F|  0.2|  -1|   3|
|2020-08-07|      T|  0.2|  -1|   4|
|2020-08-08|      T|  0.5|  -1|   5| 
|2020-08-09|      T|  0.0|  -1|   5|
+----------+-------+-----+----+----+
```

`date` : sorted nicely

`Trigger` : only **T** or **F**

`value` : any random decimal (float) value

`col1` : represents number of days and can not be lower than -1.** -1<= col1 < infinity**

`col2` : represents number of days and cannot be negative. **col2 >= 0**

**Calculation logic **

If `col1 == -1, then return 0`, otherwise if `Trigger == T`, the following diagram will help to understand the logic.

[image]

If we look at "red color", +3 came from col1 which is `col1==3` at 2020-08-01, what it means is that we jump 3 rows,and at the same time also take the difference `(col2 - col1) -1 = ( 5-3) -1 = 1.` (at 2020-08-01)  **1** represents summing the next value which is `0.2 + 0.3 = 0.5`. same logic apply for "blue color"

The "green color" is for when `trigger == "F"` then just take  `(col2 -1)=3-1 =2` (2020-08-04), **2** represent sum of next two values. which is `0.2+0.3+0.2 = 0.7`

**Edit:**

What if I want no conditions at all, let's say we have this **df**

```
TEST_schema = StructType([StructField("date", StringType(), True),\
                              StructField("value", FloatType(), True),\
                             StructField("col2", IntegerType(), True)])
TEST_data = [('2020-08-01',0.0,5),('2020-08-02',0.0,4),('2020-08-03',0.0,3),('2020-08-04',0.2,3),('2020-08-05',0.3,4),\
                 ('2020-08-06',0.2,3),('2020-08-07',0.2,4),('2020-08-08',0.5,5),('2020-08-09',0.0,5)]
rdd3 = sc.parallelize(TEST_data)
TEST_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(TEST_data, TEST_schema)
TEST_df = TEST_df.withColumn("date",to_date("date", 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
TEST_df.show() 


+----------+-----+----+
|      date|value|col2|
+----------+-----+----+
|2020-08-01|  0.0|   5|
|2020-08-02|  0.0|   4|
|2020-08-03|  0.0|   3|
|2020-08-04|  0.2|   3|
|2020-08-05|  0.3|   4|
|2020-08-06|  0.2|   3|
|2020-08-07|  0.2|   4|
|2020-08-08|  0.5|   5|
|2020-08-09|  0.0|   5|
+----------+-----+----+
```

Same logic applies for when we had Trigger == "F" condition, so `col2 -1` but no condition in this case.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, we can use Windows function `collect_list` to get all related rows, sort the array of structs by `date` and then do the aggregation based on a [slice](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.slice) of this array. the *start_idx* and *span* of each **slice** can be defined based on the following:

1. If *col1* = **-1**, *start_idx* = **1** and *span* = **0**, so nothing is aggregated
2. else if *Trigger* = **'F'**, then *start_idx* = **1** and *span* = **col2**
3. else *start_idx* = **col1+1** and *span* = **col2-col1**

Notice that the **index** for the function slice is **1-based**.

**Code:**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date, sort_array, collect_list, struct, expr
from pyspark.sql import Window

w1 = Window.orderBy('date').rowsBetween(0, Window.unboundedFollowing)

# columns used to do calculations, date must be the first field for sorting purpose
cols = ["date", "value", "start_idx", "span"]

df_new = (TEST_df
    .withColumn('start_idx', expr("IF(col1 = -1 OR Trigger = 'F', 1, col1+1)")) 
    .withColumn('span', expr("IF(col1 = -1, 0, IF(Trigger = 'F', col2, col2-col1))")) 
    .withColumn('dta', sort_array(collect_list(struct(*cols)).over(w1))) 
    .withColumn("want1", expr("aggregate(slice(dta,start_idx,span), 0D, (acc,x) -> acc+x.value)"))
)
```

**Result:**

```
df_new.show()
+----------+-------+-----+----+----+----+---------+----+--------------------+------------------+
|      date|Trigger|value|col1|col2|want|start_idx|span|                 dta|             want1|
+----------+-------+-----+----+----+----+---------+----+--------------------+------------------+
|2020-08-01|      T|  0.0|   3|   5| 0.5|        4|   2|[[2020-08-01, T, ...|0.5000000149011612|
|2020-08-02|      T|  0.0|  -1|   4| 0.0|        1|   0|[[2020-08-02, T, ...|               0.0|
|2020-08-03|      T|  0.0|  -1|   3| 0.0|        1|   0|[[2020-08-03, T, ...|               0.0|
|2020-08-04|      F|  0.2|   3|   3| 0.7|        1|   3|[[2020-08-04, F, ...|0.7000000178813934|
|2020-08-05|      T|  0.3|   1|   4| 0.9|        2|   3|[[2020-08-05, T, ...|0.9000000059604645|
|2020-08-06|      F|  0.2|  -1|   3| 0.0|        1|   0|[[2020-08-06, F, ...|               0.0|
|2020-08-07|      T|  0.2|  -1|   4| 0.0|        1|   0|[[2020-08-07, T, ...|               0.0|
|2020-08-08|      T|  0.5|  -1|   5| 0.0|        1|   0|[[2020-08-08, T, ...|               0.0|
|2020-08-09|      T|  0.0|  -1|   5| 0.0|        1|   0|[[2020-08-09, T, ...|               0.0|
+----------+-------+-----+----+----+----+---------+----+--------------------+------------------+
```

**Some Explanations:**

1. The **slice** function requires two parameters besides the targeting array. in our code, `start_idx` is the starting index and `span` is the length of the slice. In the code, I use **IF** statements to calculate *start_idx* and *span* based on the diagram specs in your original post.
2. The resulting arrays from **collect_list** + **sort_array** over a Window `w1` cover rows from the current row till the end of the Window(see `w1` assignment). we then use **slice** function inside the **aggregate** function to retrieve only necessary array items.
3. the SparkSQL builtin function [aggregate](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#aggregate) takes the following form:

   ```
    aggregate(expr, start, merge, finish)
   ```

   where the 4th argument `finish` can be skipped. in our case, it can be reformatted as (you can copy the following to replace the code inside *expr* `.withColumn('want1', expr(""" .... """)`):

   ```
    aggregate(
      /* targeting array, use slice function to take only part of the array `dta` */
      slice(dta,start_idx,span), 
      /* start, zero_value used for reduce */
      0D, 
      /* merge, similar to reduce function */
      (acc,x) -> acc+x.value,
      /* finish, skipped in the post, but you can do some post-processing here, for example, round-up the result from merge */
      acc -> round(acc, 2)
    )
   ```

   **aggregate** function works like the **reduce** function in Python, the 2nd argument is the zero value (`0D` is the shortcut for `double(0)` which is to typecast the data type of the aggregation variable `acc`).
4. as mentioned in the comments, if *col2 < col1* where *Trigger* = **'T'** and *col1* != **-1** exists, it will yield a negative *span* in the current code. In such case, we should use a full-size Window spec:

   ```
    w1 = Window.orderBy('date').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)
   ```

   and use **array_position** to find the position of the current row ([refer to one of my recent posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63158118/efficiently-calculating-weighted-rolling-average-in-pyspark-with-some-caveats/63240195#63240195)) and then calculate *start_idx* based on this position.

Comment: in case there could be `Trigger='T' AND col1 != -1 AND col2 < col1`, we will need to set Window Spec to cover all related rows `rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding,Window.unboundedFollowing)`, find the current row by array_position and then calculate start_idx.

Comment: great job.. but I dont quite understand `aggregate(slice(dta,start_idx,length_idx), 0D, (acc,x) -> acc+x.value)`  can you provide me one example maybe from row 1?

Comment: @hellotherebj, I will add explanation tomorrow morning, it's a little too late right now at my time.

Comment: @hellotherebj, I just added some explanations, also I rename a column from `length_idx` to `span`. please let me know if you need more examples.

Comment: awesome job... what if there's like col3 that's similiar to col2 and `If trigger = F then col3-1` instead of `col2 -1` what do I need to replace?

Comment: as far as I can see, just set `.withColumn('span', expr("IF(col1 = -1, 0, IF(Trigger = 'F', col3, col2-col1))"))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219763/discussion-between-hellotherebj-and-jxc).

Comment: hi Jxc, could you have a look at the edit i made for this problem? what if we have no conditions at all and just apply the col2-1 sum logic... thank you so much!!

Comment: I think you can just try: `.withColumn("want1", expr("aggregate(slice(dta,1,col2), 0D, (acc,x) -> acc+x.value)"))`. I am very busy today and will not be able to focus on this. I may need to check your new question tomorrow or late this evening.@hellotherebj

Comment: no worries, take your time jxc~ you helped me so much i really appreciate it .. !!!

Comment: hey jxc, I posted new problem, could you please take a look? thank you,,, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63608554/how-to-create-rows-and-increment-it-in-given-df-in-pyspark

Comment: hey jxc, you mentioned just try this .`withColumn("want1", expr("aggregate(slice(dta,1,col2), 0D, (acc,x) -> acc+x.value)"))` i got an error which is **AnalysisException: No such struct field value in date, col2 ** see the edit I made

Comment: ahhh nevermind , my mistake. forgot to include "value" in cols.. :)

Comment: I want to do this with window function and introducing extra columns to calculate this logic... is it even possible in here?

Comment: @hellotherebj, not sure which question you are working on. AFAIK, a WinSpec with variable size is not supported as of the current version, this will make things complex. BTW. `sort_array` used in this post might be redundant based on this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/50668635/9510729. I don't have evidence of this conclusion by myself though

Comment: i see.. thank you for the link, if we could somehow collect_list only the values using some window function. like at `2020-08-01` dta would be [0.2,0.3] and we just add them up but I dont know how to do that :(

Comment: @hellotherebj, Spark WinSpec supports only fixed Windows, either by number of rows or a fixed range (i.e. `RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND INTERVAL 7 DAYS PRECEDING`). in this example, the window-size is a variable, thus we setup a WinSpec to cover all potential rows but use `slice()` function to take only array elements located in this variable range. this somehow overcome the issue with fix-length window.

Comment: so if i do something like .rangeBetween(-days(7), 0)), will give me [0.2,0.3] only?

Comment: to calculate the value on `2020-08-01`, the window would be .rangeBetween(days(3), days(4)), both start=days(3) and end=days(4) are calculated and can be different on each date. this kind of variable-size window frame is not supported as of now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222676/discussion-between-hellotherebj-and-jxc).

Comment: hey been a long time. how you doing? to back to this question, i see that it's starting to add from the next row, is there anyway we can calculate from where start_index = 0?

Comment: eg; at 2020-08-04, when it's F. i think it's adding 08-05,08-06,08-07 which is 0.3+0.2+0.2 it should be 08-04,08-05,08-06. which is 0.2+0.3+0.3