# How to create rows and increment it in given df in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

What I want is create a new row based on the given dataframe I have and It looks like the following:

```
TEST_schema = StructType([StructField("date", StringType(), True),\
                          StructField("col1", IntegerType(), True),
                          StructField("col2", IntegerType(), True)\
                          ])
TEST_data = [('2020-08-17',0,0),('2020-08-18',2,1),('2020-08-19',0,2),('2020-08-20',3,0),('2020-08-21',4,2),\
             ('2020-08-22',1,3),('2020-08-23',2,2),('2020-08-24',1,2),('2020-08-25',3,1)]
rdd3 = sc.parallelize(TEST_data)
TEST_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(TEST_data, TEST_schema)
TEST_df = TEST_df.withColumn("date",to_date("date", 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
TEST_df.show() 

+----------+----+----+
|      date|col1|col2|
+----------+----+----+
|2020-08-17|   0|   0|
|2020-08-18|   2|   1|
|2020-08-19|   0|   2|
|2020-08-20|   3|   0|
|2020-08-21|   4|   2|
|2020-08-22|   1|   3|
|2020-08-23|   2|   2|
|2020-08-24|   1|   2|
|2020-08-25|   3|   1|
+----------+----+----+
```

Let's say I want to calculate for today's date which is `current_date()` and let's say i want to calculate `col1` as follows: `If col1 >0 return col1+col2, otherwise 0` where date == yesturday 's date which is going to be `current_date() -1`

calculate `col2` as follow, `coalesce( lag(col2),0)`

so my result dataframe would be something like this:

```
+----------+----+----+
|      date|col1|want|
+----------+----+----+
|2020-08-17|   0|   0|
|2020-08-18|   2|   0|
|2020-08-19|   0|   1|
|2020-08-20|   3|   2|
|2020-08-21|   4|   0|
|2020-08-22|   1|   2|
|2020-08-23|   2|   3|
|2020-08-24|   1|   2|
|2020-08-25|   3|   2|
|2020-08-26|   4|   1|
+----------+----+----+
```

This would be so easy if we use `withcolumn` (column based) method but I want to know how to do this with rows. My initial idea is calculate by column first and `transpose` it and make it rowbased.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can try the following:

**Step-1:** create a new dataframe with a single row having current_date() as date, nulls for col1 and col2 and then union it back to the TEST_df (**Note:** change all **2020-08-26** to `current_date()` in your final code):

```
df_new = TEST_df.union(spark.sql("select '2020-08-26', null, null"))
```

**Edit:** Practically, data are partitioned and each partition should add one row, you can do something like the following:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import current_date, col, lit

#columns used for Window partitionBy
cols_part = ['pcol1', 'pcol2']

df_today = TEST_df.select([
    (current_date() if c == 'date' else col(c) if c in cols_part else lit(None)).alias(c)
        for c in TEST_df.columns
]).distinct()

df_new = TEST_df.union(df_today)
```

**Step-2:** do calculations to fill the above null values:

```
df_new.selectExpr(
  "date", 
  "IF(date < '2020-08-26', col1, lag(IF(col1>0, col1+col2,0)) over(order by date)) as col1",
  "lag(col2,1,0) over(order by date) as col2"
).show()
+----------+----+----+
|      date|col1|col2|
+----------+----+----+
|2020-08-17|   0|   0|
|2020-08-18|   2|   0|
|2020-08-19|   0|   1|
|2020-08-20|   3|   2|
|2020-08-21|   4|   0|
|2020-08-22|   1|   2|
|2020-08-23|   2|   3|
|2020-08-24|   1|   2|
|2020-08-25|   3|   2|
|2020-08-26|   4|   1|
+----------+----+----+
```

Comment: Thank you, what if I have like 20ish  calculation columns? It wouldnt be efficient by using this methods correct?

Comment: and risky too :(

Comment: what would be the calculations for those columns, if they do the same calculation, then most likely we can use a list comprehension to iterate. in a bigdata task, doing `transpose` is usually not a good idea.

Comment: lag, lead, many if else condition logics, additions, ranking, and all the stuff that I posted and shared with you.

Comment: there are many thing you can dynamically created, for example: `df_new = TEST_df.union(spark.sql(f"select current_Date(), {','.join(20*['null'])}"))` to add a row with current_date() plus `20` nulls. write a function to define the same logic for reuse. complex logic is much easier to implement on column-level, it will be a mess if each row has a different logic.

Comment: hey jxc,please look at my problem.. thank you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63623770/how-to-change-struct-datatype-to-integer-in-pyspark

Comment: @hellotherebj, do you mind to accept the answer if it answered your question?