# How to change struct dataType to Integer in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe **df**, and one column has data type of `struct<long:bigint, string:string>`

because of this data type structure, I can not perform addition, subtration etc...

how to change `struct<long:bigint, string:string>` to just `IntegerType`??

Comment: just select `df['col_name'].long`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dot syntax to access parts of the struct column.

For example if you start with this dataframe

```python
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,(3,'x')),(4,(8, 'y'))]).toDF("col1", "col2")
df.show()
df.printSchema()
```

```
+----+------+                                                                   
|col1|  col2|
+----+------+
|   1|[3, x]|
|   4|[8, y]|
+----+------+

root
 |-- col1: long (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
```

use can select the first part of the struct column and either create a new column or replace an existing one:

```python
df.withColumn('col2', df['col2._1']).show()
```

prints

```
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|   1|   3|
|   4|   8|
+----+----+
```